# How add the name of folders to each row in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

We have multiple folders each contains many CSV files. The name for every folder is unique as it shows the meter identifier. My question is how I can load all flat files from each folder, create a dataframe out of it which includes all the csv files but create a column and write the identifier(folder name) to each of rows that they belong to :

```
Folder1 : 1.csv, 2.csv, 3.csv
Folder2: 4.csv, 5.csv, 6.csv
```

the output should include all the csv files with added column contains Folder 1 and Folder2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `org.apache.spark.sql.functions` package has function `input_file_name` that will add the column with the name of the corresponding file.  You can use it in the `select` operation, like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.input_file_name
val df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true")
    .load("directory")
    .select(input_file_name, 'some-column-name)
```

Comment: I haven't tried your solution yet, but your solution seems to read the csv file names and add them as column is that right?, what I want is read folder names and add them as column to each csv file. And can load function push all the csv files from all the folders? shouldn't we use wholeTextFile?

Comment: I tested by pointing to folder with CSV files instead of individual files